# schroot exit error: 10mount: umount: /<chroot_key>/<home>: device is busy

Tags: server, mount, chroot

- Ubuntu: 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64)
- Schroot: schroot (Debian sbuild) 1.6.8

---

There is a problem on `schroot` environment. **Does someone know the root cause of this issue?** It sometimes show the following error message when I **exit** the `schroot` environment.

```
E: 10mount: umount: /var/lib/schroot/mount/dan_chroot_env-47e94b59-c5ca-495a-955f-cd502e1b585b/home/dan: device is busy.
E: 10mount:         (In some cases useful info about processes that use
E: 10mount:          the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
E: dan_chroot_env-47e94b59-c5ca-495a-955f-cd502e1b585b: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-stop
```

It also shows the error when I run the `schroot -e --all-sessions` command.

---

The way to remove the `chroot` error is by the following steps:

1. `sudo umount -l /var/lib/schroot/mount/dan_chroot_env-47e94b59-c5ca-495a-955f-cd502e1b585b`
2. `sudo schroot -e -c dan_chroot_env-47e94b59-c5ca-495a-955f-cd502e1b585b`
3. `sudo shutdown -r now`

If I didn't reboot the server, it will show error message when I process another ssh to login to this server. I can't login to this server until I reboot it.

Comment: I have upgraded OS from `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` to `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64)` and the problem seems be resolved.